# Replace, Insert, Delete operations on IEnumerable

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I have a library that only accepts a proprietary immutable collection type. I would like to have a function that accepts one of these collections and performs some changes to this collection by returning a new collection that contains the changes made.

I would like to use a LINQ syntax instead of copying this collection to a List and back.

Add operations is easy for me: concat the enumerable with another one.
But what about Replace (at the given index, return the value given instead of that IEnumerable's value), Insert (at given index, return the given value and then continue iterating over the IEnumerable) or Delete (at given index, skip the IEnumerable's value)?

Are there functions like this available in the .NET framework or in another library? If not, how would I go about implementing these functions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can make your own extensions for these operations:

- Add

  ```
  public static IEnumerable<T> Add<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T value)
  {
      foreach (var item in enumerable)
          yield return item;

      yield return value;
  }
  ```

  or:

  ```
  public static IEnumerable<T> Add<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T value)
  {
      return enumerable.Concat(new T[] { value });
  }
  ```
- Insert

  ```
  public static IEnumerable<T> Insert<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int index, T value)
  {
      int current = 0;
      foreach (var item in enumerable)
      {
          if (current == index)
              yield return value;

          yield return item;
          current++;
      }
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  public static IEnumerable<T> Insert<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int index, T value)
  {
      return enumerable.SelectMany((x, i) => index == i ? new T[] { value, x } : new T[] { x });
  }
  ```
- Replace

  ```
  public static IEnumerable<T> Replace<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int index, T value)
  {
      int current = 0;
      foreach (var item in enumerable)
      {
          yield return current == index ? value : item;
          current++;
      }
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  public static IEnumerable<T> Replace<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int index, T value)
  {
      return enumerable.Select((x, i) => index == i ? value : x);
  }
  ```
- Remove

  ```
  public static IEnumerable<T> Remove<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int index)
  {
      int current = 0;
      foreach (var item in enumerable)
      {
          if (current != index)
              yield return item;

          current++;
      }
  }
  ```

  or

  ```
  public static IEnumerable<T> Remove<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int index)
  {
      return enumerable.Where((x, i) => index != i);
  }
  ```

Then you can make calls like this:

```
IEnumerable<int> collection = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var added = collection.Add(6);              // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
var inserted = collection.Insert(0, 0);     // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
var replaced = collection.Replace(1, 22);   // 1, 22, 3, 4, 5 
var removed = collection.Remove(2);         // 1, 2, 4, 5
```

Answer (score 3):

The question is a little broad, so I'll demonstrate a possibility for a `Replace` method. There are no methods for that in the framework that *replace* something in an `IEnumerable`, as `IEnumerable` should represent an immutable sequence.

So a naive way to return a new `IEnumerable` with replaced elements:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Replace<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T oldValue, T newValue)
    {
        return source.Select(element => element == oldValue ? newValue : element);
    }
}
```

This will iterate through the source sequence and return the source elements except for those who `Equal` the `oldValue`. Note that this uses the `==` operator and how this works depends on the type argument for `T`.

Also note that this uses **deferred execution**. The source sequence is only enumerated when you start to enumerate the resulting `IEnumerable`. So if you change the source sequence after a call to `Replace`, the resulting sequence will yield this change, too.

Implementations for `Insert` and `Delete` are straight forward, too, though you'll need to count an index in the source sequence.

Comment: I was looking for LINQ operators (which always return a new IEnumerable of course). I'm not sure if the lack of such operators can be explained by immutablity of IEnumerable though. With the existance of Where, Select, Reverse, etc, I see no reason why having my suggested functions would be against the core philosophy of LINQ. However, I do see that there is a potential risk for newbies mistaking IEnumerables for Lists and be confused that the original enumerable never changes. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 2):

`IEnumerable` is by definition a immutable enumerable collection of elements of a given type. Immutable means that you cannot modify it directly and you always have to create a new instance.

You can however use the `yield` keyword to implement this behavior, preferably using extension methods.

For example replace could look like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ReplaceAt<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int index, T item)
{
    var currentIndex = 0;
    foreach (var originalItem in collection)
    {
        if (currentIndex != index)
        {
            //keep the original item in place
            yield return originalItem;
        }
        else
        {
            //we reached the index where we want to replace
            yield return item;
        }
        currentIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a functional, more LINQ-ey feeling solution, inspired by Arturo's answer:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Replace<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, bool> selector, T value)
{
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        yield return selector(item) ? value : item;
    }
}
```

Used like this: `var newEnumerable = oldEnumerable.Replace(x => x.Id == 1, newItem)`